# Fundamental Group of $(S^1 \vee S^1) \times S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

what is the fundamental group of $X= (S^1 \vee S^1) \times S^1?$

One way to see this is it should be equal to $(\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. This is simply obtained by considering the fundamental group of $X \times Y$ in terms of fundamental group of $X$ and that of $Y$.

Another what I did is by using van-kampen's theorem. I considered points $$a \in (S^1 \vee 0) \times S^1$$ and $$b \in (0 \vee S^1) \times S^1$$

Then I considered the open sets $U=X-a$ and $V=X-b$. I hope I am able to put it properly.  What I am trying to say is $U$ is union of first torus and a bit of other torus.  And similary we choose $V$. Then $U \cap V$ deformation retracts to $0 \times S^1$ which is the circle where both the torus are attached.

Then Van-kampen's gives the fundamental group to be

$$\pi_1(X)=\langle a,b,c \colon ab=ba, bc=cb\rangle$$.

Morever this doesn't mean its the direct sum of $3$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ as $ac$ is not equal to $ca$. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Your two methods are correct and lead to the same result. It is indeed not $\Bbb Z^3,$ the latter being abelian.